# some vertices won't snap when using knife tool

Tags: snapping, knife-tool

I try to cut through my face by just selecting vertices with knife tool, but it snaps only on one vertex so obviously i am doing some beginner mistake here.

What do i have to do that it snaps to all vertices?

[image]

[image]

blend file:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertices you're trying to snap to are not part of the face you're trying to cut through. You can't cut through nothing to join a vertex to another one.

[image]

Comment: of course not...that's why i want to cut through....

Comment: then the snapping makes just "a bit" sense...if i cannot snap to "all" vertices...or can i change that behaviour somehow?

Comment: umpf...that's disappointing. i just wanted to cut out that section which i cannot snap :(. ok, i ask another one how i cut that through....

Comment: my answer is not accurate enough, I need to formulate it correctly

Comment: Better to use a boolean modifier for that I'd have thought.

Comment: Yes duplicate the shape, extrude it, use it as boolean